# Many2many field does not store the values

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

After pressing Save button, the Many2many field does not store the values

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Expected behavior:
It should store the values to use it later

***edits:***

Models:

```py
    @api.onchange('Start_Date', 'Cycle_Type', 'Cycle_val')
    def _compute_Stop_Date(self):
        date_range_obj= self.env['working.shift.date.range']
        for record in self:
            days_to_add1=0
            days_to_add=0
            list_date_range_ids = []
            current_date = fields.Datetime.from_string(record.Start_Date)
            day_on=fields.Datetime.from_string(record.Start_Date)
            if record.Cycle_Type == 'day':
                days_to_add=record.Cycle_val           
                while days_to_add > 1:
                    date_range_id= date_range_obj.create({'date':current_date,'day':current_date.strftime('%A')})
                    list_date_range_ids.append(date_range_id.id)
                    current_date += timedelta(days=1) 
                    days_to_add -= 1

            else:
                days_to_add1=record.Cycle_val
                days_to_add=days_to_add1*7           
                while days_to_add > 1:
                    date_range_id= date_range_obj.create({'date':current_date,'day':current_date.strftime('%A')})
                    list_date_range_ids.append(date_range_id.id)
                    current_date += timedelta(days=1) 
                    days_to_add -= 1                

            record.Stop_Date=current_date
            record.Stop_Date_day=current_date.strftime('%A')
            record.Start_Date_day=day_on.strftime('%A')
            date_range_id= date_range_obj.create({'date':current_date,'day':current_date.strftime('%A')})
            list_date_range_ids.append(date_range_id.id)
            record.Date_range = [(6,0,list_date_range_ids)]
```

Comment: hello,
I am facing same problem so you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see here: [Added users to Many2many field disappear after click save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283436/added-users-to-many2many-field-disappear-after-click-save)

This seems to be an odd behaviour of the many2many-Widget in the view which gives a wrong format back for the values. Especially if the relation has been filled by an onchange. The list comes as [[1, id_1, {}], [1, id_2, {}]] but expected is [[**4**, id_1, {}], [**4**, id_2, {}]] to really create the relation.

The OCA has a ticket: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/21285 but as Odoo 10.0 is out of support, there won't be a real fix.

In the linked question there is a nice implementation to have a workaround:

```
def _fix_values(self, values):
    # Die Features kommen leider in der falschen Form an... [[1, <ID>, {}]] ist falsch,
    # dadurch wird nur ein Update der Features getriggert. Notwendig ist ein [[4, <id>, 0]]
    # welches die Relation erzeugt.
    if 'ems_sentinel_feature_ids' in values:
        new_feat_id = []
        for f in values['ems_sentinel_feature_ids']:
            new_f = [4, f[1], 0]
            new_feat_id.append(new_f)
        values['ems_sentinel_feature_ids'] = new_feat_id

    return values

@api.multi
def create(self, vals):
    _logger.info('Creating license.module.product: {0}'.format(vals))
    vals = self._fix_values(vals)
    return super(DswLicenseModuleProduct, self).create(vals)
```

Another approach is to use the 'many2many_tags'-widget, wich delivers the correct array.

Hope this will help others whom stumble like me over this unanswered question.