# Added users to Many2many field disappear after click save

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I try to add users to many2many field. It's working to moment before clicking save.
When i click save it's disappear. But if i before add some extra element do this field, other element stay after clicking save.

Code:

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('partner_id')
def find_projects(self):
    mail_followers = self.env["mail.followers"]
    projects_follower_id = mail_followers.search([('partner_id', '=', self.partner_id.id), ('res_model', '=', 'project.project')])
    projects_list = []
    for x in range(len(projects_follower_id)):
        project_id = self.env["project.project"].search([('id', '=', projects_follower_id[x].res_id), ('active', '=', True)])
        if project_id and project_id not in projects_list:
            projects_list.append(project_id.id)

    self.debug_projects = len(projects_follower_id)
    self.debug_projects2 = projects_follower_id
    self.debug_projects3 = projects_list
    self.project_ids = [[6, 0, projects_list]]
```

Screens:

One element before click save:

[image]

After click save:

[image]

Before click save add manually extra element:

[image]

After click save with one manually added element:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In `onchange` don't use `command list` when you want to update the value of `many2many`, Use `RecordSet`, I'm going to simplify your code a little bit:

```
# don't use api.multi because it's by default multi with onchange, constraints, depends
@api.onchange('partner_id')
def find_projects(self):
    # extract followers <RecordsSet>
    projects_followers = self.env["mail.followers"].search([('partner_id', '=', self.partner_id.id), ('res_model', '=', 'project.project')])
    # extract all project ids without duplication <list of int >
    project_ids = projects_followers.mapped('res_id')
    # no need to pass active = True Odoo by default add it
    # search for porject <RecordSet>
    projects = self.env["project.project"]search([('id', 'in', project_ids)])
    # for debuging
    self.debug_projects = len(projects_followers)
    self.debug_projects2 = projects_followers
    self.debug_projects3 = project_ids

    # don't use any command by default Odoo detect witch project still in the field
    # and witch one are added when you inspect write you will find that new ones are added 
    # by (4, id)  the ones that were removed are (3, id)
    self.project_ids = projects
```

**Edits:**

When I investigated the dictionary values passed to create and write, Odoo was converting the commands to only `update` commands, after I added by onchange event records with ids `1,2` the commands in the dictionary were like this!!:

```
      'my_many2may' : [[1, 1, {u'name': u'1'}], [1, 2, {u'name': u'2'}]]
```

In new version of Odoo `(> 11.0)` the commands passed by `many2many` are replace commands: `[(6, 0, ids)]` `(bug was fixed)`:

And to fix this in your case just override the create aand write to fix the commads of your field:

```py
def _fix_vals(self, vals):
    """ fix bug of ignored record added by onchange event."""
    commands = vals.get('project_ids', [])
    if commands and not any(command[0] == 6 for command in commands):
        vals['project_ids'] +=  [(4, command[1]) for command in commands if command[0] == 1]


@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    self._fix_vals(vals)
    return super(YourClassName, self).create(vals)


@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    self._fix_vals(vals)
    return super(YourClassName, self).write(vals)
```

so basically when I fix the commonds like this:

```
    [[1, 1, {u'name': u'1'}], [1, 2, {u'name': u'2'}]]
    # to this
    [(4,1), (4,2), [1, 1, {u'name': u'1'}], [1, 2, {u'name': u'2'}]]
```

**Note:** I noticed that when you add a record manually the command `(6,0, ids)` is passed the problem will not appear this why I checked if that command exist before fixing them

Comment: Thx for response.
I use your code but still i have that same issue.

Comment: And your comments are very helpful :)

Comment: @LukaszK i'm trying to figure out why, just confirm the type of project_ids is many2many?

Comment: i find the problem, this issue do this:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/14761

It's not working in default view, i need to add widget.

Comment: @LukaszK using this widget my be a solution for you but what if you want to show a tree view, check my edits the problem that when all record are added from onchange event the command `(6,0, ids)` is not passed.

Comment: Tree view will be better :)
Where i can fix_vals ? Can you write me path where i can put this ?

Comment: Just add the three method to your file that contains onchange method, sorry i forget to explain my code in the answer, just use all the method on my answer together

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this bug:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/14761

In default view it not working, when i add `widget="many2many_tags"` in view it start working.

Comment: this means that the command `(6,0,ids)` is passed by this widget